# What to use as storage mechanism which can be accessible by application and windows executable on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS infrastructure, I would like to know what storage mechanism should I use which can be accessible by my war (hosted in AWS elasticbeanstalk) and one windows service hosted on one of my AWS machine. I have little knowledge about S3, EBS and EFS.

Use Case:

1. my webapp in elasticbeanstalk would like to create objects in some storage system.
2. my executable on one of aws machine produces files that should be accessible by my webapp deployed in elasticbeanstalk

Questions:

1. Is it possible to share some storage to both my webapp and my executable.
2. If answer of 1 is yes, What storage mechanism should I use ?

Please advise.

Comment: it actually depends on for what purpose you want to use your storage, for example storing static resources like images etc please specify the use case

Comment: @varnit - I updated my use case

Comment: what do you mean by executable here ?

Comment: @varnit- executable - one of the windows service (.exe) on one of AWS machine

Comment: i have updated the answer please go through it, ask me if you have any other issue i'm open for discussion

Comment: @varnit, My understanding is that ebs can not used if my application is deployed on load balancer (with multiple EC2 instances). I would like to store my files stored in hierarchical structure. For example, every user on my app have one folder named user id and can have different folders inside it.

Comment: Ebs has nothing to do with load balancer its just a virtual disk that you attach to your ec2 machine, in my opinion you should first give a try to s3 otherwise you should go for efs

Answer (score 1):

S3 is Simple Storage Service that is reachable through a web interface. I reckon this is what you are looking for. It is reachable through an URL and is used for storing objects such as files, images, and so on.

EBS is a virtual hard disk that is connected to an EC2 instance (virtual machine).

EFS is Elastic File System used for Linux.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Comment: may be he needs block storage, s3 is an object storage and efs is not only for linux it supports windows, and it can be shared between various ec2 instances and its a block storage

Answer (score 1):

If full hierarchical file system is not needed and you need to store plain object which seems to be the case according to use case given by you then Amazon s3 is the way to go.

Amazon EBS is the block storage service that can only be attached to one machine it resembles the physical hardisk attached to your home computer for more information read this.

[EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/)

Amazon EFS stands for elastic file system its also a block storage service, its different from EBS in terms that it can be shared accross multiple machines, it resembles the NAS in a datacenter. for more information on EFS read this.

[EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/)